# hashCode of Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY

Tags: java, hashcode

I've recently encountered an odd situation when computing the hash Code of tuples of doubles in java. Suppose that you have the two tuples (1.0,1.0) and (Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY). Using the idiom stated in [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/)(Item 7), these two tuples would not be considered equal (Imagine that these tuples are objects). However, using the formula stated in Item 8 to compute `hashCode()` of each tuple evaluates to the same value.

So my question is: is there something strange about this formula that I missed out on when I was writing my formulas, or is it just an odd case of hash-code collisions?

Here is my short, comparative method to illustrate the situation (I wrote it as a JUnit4 test, but it should be pretty easily converted to a `main` method).

```
@Test
public void testDoubleHashCodeAndInfinity(){
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 1.0;
    double c = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double d = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    int prime = 31;
    int result1 = 17;
    int result2 = 17;

    long temp1 = Double.doubleToLongBits(a);
    long temp2 = Double.doubleToLongBits(c);
    //this assertion passes successfully
    assertTrue("Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY" +
            "==Double.doubleToLongBits(1.0)",temp1!=temp2);

    result1 = prime*result1 + (int)(temp1^(temp1>>>32));
    result2 = prime*result2 + (int)(temp2^(temp2>>>32));

    //this assertion passes successfully 
    assertTrue("Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY.hashCode()" +
            "==(1.0).hashCode()",result1!=result2);

    temp1 = Double.doubleToLongBits(b);
    temp2 = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    //this assertion should pass successfully
    assertTrue("Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY" +
            "==Double.doubleToLongBits(1.0)",temp1!=temp2);

    result1 = prime*result1+(int)(temp1^(temp1>>>32));
    result2 = prime*result2+(int)(temp2^(temp2>>>32));

    //this assertion fails!
    assertTrue("(1.0,1.0).hashCode()==" +
            "(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).hashCode()",
            result1!=result2);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is a hash collision. Does it have collisions like this for many other tuples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a coincidence. However, it's an interesting one. Try this:

```
Double d1 = 1.0;
Double d2 = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

int hash1 = d1.hashCode();
int hash2 = d2.hashCode();

// These both print -1092616192
// This was me using the wrong hash combinator *and*
// the wrong tuples... but it's interesting
System.out.println(hash1 * 17 + hash2);
System.out.println(hash2 * 17 + hash1);

// These both print -33554432
System.out.println(hash1 * 31 + hash1);
System.out.println(hash2 * 31 + hash2);
```

Basically the bit patterns of the hash determine this. hash1 (1.0's hash code) is 0x3ff00000 and hash2 (infinity's hash code) is 0x7ff00000. That sort of hash and those sort of multipliers produces that sort of effect...

Executive summary: it's a coincidence, but don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a coincidence, but that sure does not help when you are trying to use the hashCode in a Map to cache objects that have doubles in tuples. I ran into this when creating a map of Thermostat temp settings classes. Then other tests were failing because I was getting the wrong object out of the Map when using the hashCode as the key.

The solution I found to fix this was to create an appended String of the 2 double parameters and called hashCode() on the String. To avoid the String overhead I cached the hashcode.

```
private volatile hashCode;
@Override public int hashCode()
{
  int result = hashCode;
  if (result == 0) {
     String value = new StringBuilder().append(d1).append(d2).toString();
     result = value.hashCode();
     hashCode = result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you made some mistake somewhere. A hash collision may lower the efficiency of a `HashMap`, but it can't break it. Your problem with Thermostat may be cause by really badly implemented `hashCode`, i.e., inconsistent with `equals`. For example, implementing `int hashCode() {return 43;}` leads to terrible performance, but to no errors!